# Find one word from given array in string

Tags: mongodb

Let's assume we have a user given array:

```
q = ['dolor', 'sed']
```

And a item in my db is:

```
{//data,
 'paragraphs' : [{ 'header' : 'Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Nullam venenatis lectus risus, a interdum lectus rhoncus sed. Vestibulum sit amet massa eu metus iaculis laoreet et non est. ',
                 //mode data
                 },
                 { .. }]
}
```

I want to find if the 'paragraphs.header' has the word `dolor` **or** `sed`.

I tried `$in` and `search` with no success. What should I use?

Comment: You should use a real text-search engine if you want a solution with reasonable performance. This query is not a good fit for MongoDB. Even the full-text support coming in 2.6 (which is in preview now) is going to have limited features when compared to a full-offering.

Comment: So MongoDB is a bad idea for this kind of operations.Your suggestion? MySql?

Comment: No, something like ElasticSearch or Solr (both are service layers on top of a common search engine called Lucene).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Infective way would be to use regular expressions:

```
db.foo.find({"paragraphs.header": {$in: [/dolor/, /sed/]}})
```

Because none of this is anchored the beginning of the string it means you cannot use indexes and you'll have to perform full scan to find matching documents.

If you want effective way you should look at [TextSearch](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/core/text-search/).

- start mongod with `--setParameter textSearchEnabled=true`
- create text index `db.foo.ensureIndex({"paragraphs.header": "text"})`
- search `db.foo.runCommand("text", {search: "dolor sed"})`

You can specify language when you create text index or run `text` command but unfortunately [Latin is not supported](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/command/text/#text-search-languages) ;)

Comment: Never liked Latin :) However I checked the doc and noticed [this](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/tutorial/enable-text-search/). So I guess regex is slow (and also cpu demanding?) but text search is fast and huge.

Comment: That's right. MongoDB works pretty well with ElasticSearch if you need full text search capabilities.